# Unable to get timing of functions in Node profiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling

First of all my apologies if this questions has been already asked, I searched but could not find an answer.
I have a performance issue and need to profile a local node app and include information like:

- how much time it take for each function (or maybe line of code) to run
- how many times was each function ran

Please advise any good solution. Thank you in advance.

P.S. Just to note the app.js app is just a simple file that contains 2 small functions. I just need a POC to see how it works.

I've been searching for several days but could not find an appropriate solution. The options I found were:

- run `node --prof app.js`. This does profile the local app, but only include information on processor ticks used per function, but not time user for each function. This also has a `node --prof -log-timer-events app.js`, however, to be able to plot the result I need to build the v8 source code, get a d8 shell app (develope shell app included in v8 engine) to be able to use the v8 tools, and I think I lack some skills on building the v8 engine
- tried to install v8-profiler module from npm.  Was not able to install the module, getting some error on installation (binaries not found on amazon url)
- tried to install profiler module (https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler) but seems deprecated
- a module called 0x, but that also doesn't show exact timings, but only creates a flamegraph of the cpu ticks.
- a couple other modules that I can't remember the name already :)

Comment: cpu ticks / cpu frequency = time ?

Comment: Usually, when dealing with speed issues with NodeJS, one narrows down the bottleneck to functions level, and see what can be improved and what not. Information provided by `--prof` (again, usually) seems to be sufficient enough for that (the technique is described in this [blog post](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/)) Perhaps it makes sense to discuss the problem itself? )